# Android studios gradle.properties

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Can someone help me solve this issue. yes I have seen this question before but from years earlier than 2016. The issue:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.

> Java heap space
>   ties file.
>   For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
>   *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
>   [Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
> [Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

How do I fix this error? Please help with solutions from 2016. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m what if you remove this line?

Comment: have you added Inside your manifest-- Apllication  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: I just tried both and that didn't seem to help

Comment: try uncommenting `# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` line and increase the jvmargs size

Answer (score 0):

First try to clean and rebuild your project .. if your issue remains still same Then update your SDK and import your code again.

But if both of method not works then use this alternative.
After updating sdk choose a empty project and build all third party libraries in your gradle. After this copy paste one by your code in new project with their repective places.

this method is slight lengthy and not up to standard but it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue just now. Managed to fix it by increasing the Java max heap size.

Changed org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m to
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4000m

in gradle.properties